# Failed to add SharePointPnPCore2016 Package in VS2017

Tags: .net, sharepoint, console-application, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I am trying to add "SharePointPnPCore2016" package from NuGet Package Manager but I get this error:

> Failed to add reference. The package 'SharePointPnPCore2016' tried to
>   add a framework reference to 'Microsoft.Office.Client.Policy,
>   Version=16.0.0.0' which was not found in the GAC. This is possibly a
>   bug in the package. Please contact the package owners for assistance.
>   Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

The application where I am trying to add this package is using .Net Framework 4.5.2.

Any thoughts what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work I initially installed the individual dlls that was prompted. There were 11 such packagaes that had to be installed. But later I realized that I had to explicitly install 
"**SharePointPnPCoreOnline**" which I guess is alternative to "OfficeDevPnPCore16". OfficeDevPnPCore16 shows as deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the CSOM-package first; so for SharePoint 2016 that would be
`Install-Package Microsoft.SharePoint2016.CSOM`
`Install-Package SharePointPnPCore2016`
and for SharePoint 2019 you need to install
`Install-Package Microsoft.SharePoint2019.CSOM`
`Install-Package SharePointPnPCore2019`